# boost::mpi 1.53 in place all_reduce

Tags: c++, boost, mpi

How to do in place all reduce with `boost::mpi` 1.53? (that is the version for CentOS 7)

boost 1.61 has `boost::mpi::inplace_t` ([doc](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_61_0/doc/html/mpi/reference.html)) but boost 1.53 does not ([doc](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/mpi/reference.html#header.boost.mpi_hpp)).

For 1.61, I can use:

```
boost::mpi::all_reduce(
    comm, 
    boost::mpi::inplace_t<int*>(ptr_int_array), 
    n_elements, 
    op);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't want to have an extra field of `out_value` you can overwrite `in_value` by setting to return value of the function.

```
#include <boost/mpi.hpp>

int main()
{
    boost::mpi::environment env;
    boost::mpi::communicator comm;    

    // set in_value to whatever you want.
    int in_value = comm.rank() 
    // overwrite.
    in_value = all_reduce(comm, in_value, std::plus<double>());   

    return 0;
}
```